# ASP.Net Data Bind Environmental Issue

Tags: asp.net, data-binding

Using a repeater to data bind a common control we are having issues where the data bound control is not being bound in different environments.

The old works on my machine issue.

We have the below repeater:

```
<web:Repeater ID="rptVehicles" runat="server" DataType="Entities.VehicleSummary" OnItemDataBound="rptItemList_OnItemDataBound">
<ItemTemplate>
    <div style="display:none">  
        <p>Container Item = <%# (Container.DataItem == null) ? "null" : "not null" %></p>
        <p>Container Item Id = <%# (Container.DataItem.ID == null) ? "null" : "not null" %></p>
        <p>Container Item Id = <%# Container.DataItem.ID %></p>
    </div>
    <common:VehicleItem runat="server" ID="itmVehicle" DataSource="<%# Container.DataItem %>" ImageDefinition="<%# this.ImageDefinition %>"  />
</ItemTemplate>
</web:Repeater>
```

And the contents of the Vehicle Item user control:

```
<div class="m-vitem">
<div style="display:none">
    <p>DataSourceSet = <%# this.DataSourceSet %></p>
    <p>Item DataSource = <%# (this.DataSource == null)? "null" : "not null" %></p>
</div>
```

On local the data source setter gets called passing in the Vehicle Summary entity.

DataSourceSet  property is set to true in the DataSource property setter, on local its output is true on testing its false.

We are using different .Net versions on local and testing environments, does anyone know if there are any difference in the data bind handling between versions and what can be done, or am I barking up the wrong tree?

LOCAL - Microsoft .NET Framework Version:2.0.50727.4961; ASP.NET Version:2.0.50727.4955
TESTING- Microsoft .NET Framework Version:2.0.50727.3082; ASP.NET Version:2.0.50727.3082

Comment: What values are you getting for Container.DataItem on local vs. test? Are they the same?
Also, where is the repeater getting bound on the test machine? Did you make sure it's actually getting bound to data?

Comment: Its bound on pre_render, I have also moved it to on load as well. Same outcome.  If I move the entire Vehicle Item control from the common user control to inside the ItemTemplate of the repeater it works, but we a trying to promote code and control re-use.

The "Container Item Id" in the repeaters Item Template is being rendered so its being data bound. The values for Container Data Item are the same on local and test.  Same DB server just different Web server, they also output the same vehicle id.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure why this is happening other than a version issue, but did you try calling `base.OnDataBinding(EventArgs.Empty);` from an overridden `OnDataBinding` method in your control?

Comment: Just tired that, same issue. However I have narrowed it down it some specifically to do with the "DataSource" property.  If I add another property on to the user control called "DataSourceB" of the same type and then pass in the Container.DataItem it works, just not "DataSource". I am reviewing now.

Comment: Ok, getting closer I am overriding the "DataSource" property on the Vehicle Item user control its calling the base correctly but there is some additional setup within the setter that is required.  However if you remove the override it works but the additional setup isn't done. Any ideas on why overriding the property causes it not to data bind, the base property is marked as virtual.

Comment: Fixed it, not sure why I can't data bind the overridden property so the answer goes to who can tell me why. The fix was to use the OnDataBinding to do the setup I needed instead of in the property setter then getting rid of the overridden property. I like this way a lot better make far more sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the code in your base property that was performing the set up was not being called since the overriding property on your vehicles entity. Marking a base property as *virtual* only makes the compiler choose *which* version of the property it needs to use at run-time. It does not mean that the base property setter's code is run before/after the sub class` property setter.

Also, it doesn't make sense to actually do any 'set up' in a property, you'd ideally want to move that to the base constructor, where it would be executed if you call your base constructor from your object's constructor. Alternatively but less ideally, you could perform the set up in your overriding property as well.

Moving the set up code to `OnDataBinding` works for you since the `DataBind` event is fired automatically whenever you set the `DataSource` property of the repeater.